# How to add methods to NSTableViewDelegate protocol?

Tags: swift, cocoa, delegates, nstableview, swift-protocols

I'd like to expand `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol with a few custom methods. For instance, I want my custom `NSTableView` subclass to inform the delegate on some specific events. Is it possible not to create another protocol but to add custom methods to the existing one? What would be the best approach here?

I've tried to write and extension to `NSTableViewDelegate`, and methods get called, but in this extension I have no access to the delegate class (my subclass of `NSViewController`). And it kind of ruins the whole idea, because the controller needs to respond to events in its specific way.

So: how one could add methods to `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol and provide implementation in the delegate class?

Sorry for verbosity :)

Example code (in the project it differs a bit, but the idea is the same):

```
extension NSTableViewDelegate {
    func didBecomeFirstResponder(_ tableView: NSTableView) {
        isTableViewFirstResponder = true //warning: Use of unresolved identifier 'isTableViewFirstResponder'
    }

    func didResignFirstResponder(_ tableView: NSTableView) {
        isTableViewFirstResponder = false   //warning: Use of unresolved identifier 'isTableViewFirstResponder'
    }
}
```

`isTableViewFirstResponder` is a property of the delegate class.
Swift just doesn't know where to look for it. How can I specify the class where `isTableViewFirstResponder` is declared?

Comment: `but in this extension I have no access to the delegate class` — can you explain this? How exactly do you want to access it? It would be better if you add your code.

Comment: Thank you for attention to the question. Added a code snippet.

Comment: `NSTableViewDelegate` does not know about `isTableViewFirstResponder`. I think you want to extend the NSTableView rather than the delegate.

Comment: @shallowThought, yes, that is my point: `NSTableViewDelegate` does not know about `isTableViewFirstResponder`. Could you please explain your idea a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add a method to this protocol. But the implementation will reside in extension, there is no obvious way to implement additional methods in the class that conforms the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol and thus can see only stuff that exists in `NSTableViewDelegate`s implementation. `isTableViewFirstResponder` does not exist in `NSTableViewDelegate`s implementation and thus is not known to the extension.

Afaik it is not possible to add a stored property to an extension, thus I think you have to introduce an extra Protcol, which also makes sense imo. as it is no delegate responsability, but a responder one:

```
protocol NSTableViewResponder {
    var isTableViewFirstResponder: Bool {get set}
}

extension NSTableViewResponder {
    mutating func didBecomeFirstResponder(_ tableView: NSTableView) {
        isTableViewFirstResponder = true
    }

    mutating func didResignFirstResponder(_ tableView: NSTableView) {
        isTableViewFirstResponder = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `isTableViewFirstResponder` is a property of the delegate class. My table view subclass informs its delegate about gaining/resigning first responder status via 2 methods described in the question, and the delegate has to store the status in its property, `isTableViewFirstResponder` boolean. I just want to implement these 2 methods in the delegate class, as all usual `NSTableViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: I can not find `isTableViewFirstResponder` [in the NSTableView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdelegate).

Comment: surely, because it is a custom property of the delegate (say, `MyViewController`).

Comment: Ahh. It's a property of your class that _conforms to_ the delegate protocoll. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I had implemented before asking the question. It works, surely. I am just new to all this protocol-oriented stuff and thought there could be a way to add methods to the protocol without creating a new one. Thank you.

Comment: You _can_ extend methods to a protocol without creating a new one. You _can not_ extend stored properties.

Comment: Yeah, Xcode is pretty straightforward about that ) Thanks again, anyway.